# Is that a microphone?

Tags: microphone, sound, calibration

Can someone determine if that's a microphone and tell me the model or brand?

[image: http://imgur.com/a/Z9SWr]

Comment: It's a Yamaha, that's all I could say. Never seen one before.

Answer (score 1):

That is a Yamaha YPAO Calibration Microphone:

[image: Yamaha YPAO Calibration Microphone]

It is used to calibrate amplifier/speaker systems in relation to the room you place it in.

YPAO stands for "Yamaha Parametric Acoustic Optimiser" and here is a video about the process (in which the microphone is used):